# Set resource ID of String in code

Tags: java, android, string

Is there a way to set the ID of a string in code, so I can call the string in other Activities by `R.strings.codegenstring`. I can't predefine them in the `string.xml` since there will be a variable amount of code generated strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But you can define a String as static

```
public class A {
    public static String s;

    public void yourStringGeneratingFunction() {
        s = "blahblah";
    }
}
```

And access it from another class by:

```
A.s
```

Comment: Or, simply give your string a value on declaration, e.g. `public static final String s = "BLAH";`

Answer (score 0):

No, there no way. To call string by **R.string.codegenstring** you must define public static string variable in **R** class. But **R** class are built by Android during compiling and you shouldn't modify it.